# Python returns a generator object when trying to print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to print using list comprehension where I want to print each element individually in iterations. The code in question:

```
str1 = "You don't know how amazing it is to learn how to program!"

list1 = str1.split(" ")

print(i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5)
```

But when I try to run the code it spits out:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001F4212233C0>
```

And the desired output would be:

```
AMAZING
PROGRAM!
```

Other than using a normal for loop, what can I do here to achieve what I want using just one line of code inside of the `print()` function?

Comment: You have to consume the generator: `print(*(i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5))`. If you want newlines use the `sep` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The form

```
(i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5)
```

is a generator expression (a `genexpr`). It won't have a value until it's iterated, and `print()` doesn't iterate objects by itself. (It only makes strings out of them, and `<generator object <genexpr>>` is the string form of a generator expression.

To fix this, you have a couple of options (aside from using a list comprehension):

- Use `"\n".join()` on the genexpr to make it a string joined by newlines:

  ```
  print("\n".join(i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5))
  ```
- You can splat the generator expression into arguments for `print` with the `*` operator and tell `print` to separate values by newlines:

  ```
  print(*(i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5), sep="\n")
  ```

Comment: So this works because join() iterates objects and print() doesn't? My bad if these are dumb questions, just getting into python.

Comment: Join must iterate the objects to get a single string out of them, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the generator expression inside `join()` to print each item on a line by itself:

```
print("\n".join(i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5))
```

which produces the desired output:

```
AMAZING
PROGRAM!
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the print statement would return a generator only. If you would like to get the desired output, try doing

```
print([i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5])
```

or

```
[print(i.upper()) for i in list1 if len(i) > 5]
```

Comment: This won't yield the desired output though.

Comment: These don't output the desired output. For the second option, it is close but at the end of the output a bunch of "None" are returned. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Your could try getting the output in an array

```
str1 = "You don't know how amazing it is to learn how to program!"
list1 = str1.split(" ")
print([i.upper() for i in list1 if len(i) > 5])
```

Comment: This won't print what OP wants.